# Quadratic equation problem

Tags: quadratics

Quadratic eq which takes the 
`value (y) = 41 at x= -2  , the value (y) = 20 at x =5`

when x = 2 -> a4-b2+c=y ...

how to find a,b,c,y

here is original question:
[Question's pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrQEy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your aren't supposed to find y.  y is variable.

The quadratic equation is in the form $y = ax^2 + b^x + c$.  When x = -2 you have y = 41 so $41 = a*(-2)^2 +b*(-2) + c$.  When x = 5, y= 20 so $20 = a*5^2 + b*5 + c$.  When x = 2, y = $a4-b2+c$ so $a4-b2+c = a*2^2 + b*2 + c$.

You have three equations and three unknowns, a, b, c.  So you should be able to solve a, b, c and express $y = a*x^2 + b*x +c$ with the proper values of a, b, c.

Comment: i thought, it'll be solved by system of equations like 

"4    -2  1  41 
 25   5   1  20" 

i tried, but variable' < equations and i couldnt find proper values of  variables...